# Beginner-box and red-box tags

Tags: discussion, tags

I've just created the [beginner-box](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tags/beginner-box/info) and [red-box](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tags/red-box/info) tags, should they exist and should they be a synonyms for each other or should there be one starter-kit tag to rule them all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no value in combining them, and "red-box" is a bad tag because there is the original D&D red box and the new 4e red box.  Usually just using the correct version tag (becmi, dnd-4e, pathfinder) is sufficient.

Comment: Do you think there's use in having a single `starter-kit` tag at all?

Comment: No. What question besides an arbitrary "compare and contrast" would be useful to go across all games' starter kits?  Including non-D&D starter kits?  Tags are for helpful groupings of questions so people interested in a topic can find the related questions.  That tag doesn't serve that purpose at all.

Comment: I've started GMing from scratch with a Beginner Box and I'd be interested to see questions other people have had using it or the red box? Could just be me though, and might be able to find them by using search.